# adding PHP to an external JAVASCRIPT file

Tags: php, javascript

I have a website template which uses an external JAVSCRIPT file to plot data on to the graph. what I want to do is swap the demo content for php variables.

Original graph data

```
  var data = [{
  label: "Facebook",
  data: [[1, 2], [2, 37], [3, 12], [4, 72], [5, 24], [6, 113], [7, 27]]
  },
  {
  label: "Google+",
  data: [[1, 3], [2, 45], [3, 16], [4, 48], [5, 12], [6, 125], [7, 26]]
  }];
```

MY Attempt

```
 var data = [{
label: "Facebook",
 data: [[<?php echo '$daysago7'; ?>, 2], [<?php echo '$daysago6'; ?>, 37], [<?php echo   '$daysago5'; ?>, 12], [<?php echo '$daysago4'; ?>, 72], [<?php echo '$daysago3'; ?>, 24],   [<?php echo '$daysago2'; ?>, 113], [<?php echo '$daysago1'; ?>, 27]]
 },
 {
label: "Google+",
data: [[<?php echo '$daysago7'; ?>, 3], [<?php echo '$daysago6'; ?>, 45], [<?php echo '$daysago5'; ?>, 16], [<?php echo '$daysago4'; ?>, 48], [<?php echo '$daysago3'; ?>, 12], [<?php echo '$daysago2'; ?>, 125], [<?php echo '$daysago1'; ?>, 26]]
```

}]

When I include my version, i get no graph at all.

Comment: Today I stumbled across a very good answer to the question and [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-code-in-my-javascript-not-work)

Comment: Are your variables getting set and is the server interpreting the php in your Javascript file?
(what is the extension of the include you are trying to do).
Seeing the structure of what you are trying to include/use might help answer your question.
You are also missing a closing ; in your version. }]
should be }];

Comment: My guess is that PHP isn't processing that file.  Try to change the file to a `.php` file instead of a `.js` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writting php inside .js file it won't work. However you can do

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/some_file.php"></script>
```

and make that .php file output javascript.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can create a file *javascript.php* with this code:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript");?>
var data = [{

    }, { label: "Google+",  data: [[ < ?php echo '$daysago7'; ? >, 3], [ < ?php echo '$daysago6'; ? >, 45], [ < ?php echo '$daysago5'; ? >, 16], [ < ?php echo '$daysago4'; ? >, 48], [ < ?php echo '$daysago3'; ? >, 12], [ < ?php echo '$daysago2'; ? >, 125], [ < ?php echo '$daysago1'; ? >, 26]]}]
```

Comment: The header is very important, then use it in a script tag like this:

<script type="text/javascript" src="js-stuff.js.php"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Well, I use to do it like this:

**PHP (Controller)**

```
$dataPlot = [
    'label' => 'Facebook',
    'data' => [...]
];
```

**View (PHP, Twig, dunno)**

```
<div data-plot="<?php echo json_encode($dataPlot) ?>"></div>
```

**JS (using jQuery)**

```
$(function() {

    $('[data-plot]').each(function(i) {

        var div = $(this);
        var data = div.data('plot');

        div.someJQueryChartPlugin(data);

    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
[data-plot] {
    ...
}
```

This way you don't need to generate a JS with PHP (and send the right headers to make the browser understand what it is) and can add lots of charts easily.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the apostrophes from your code.

Instead of

```
<?php echo '$daysago7';?>
```

use this

```
<?php echo $daysago7;?>
```

Apostrophes interprets `$` sign as normal sign, not as php variable.

If you use php file for javascript as the other answer suggests, just add this header at the very top (before any whitespace) of the file:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript");?>
```

To help the client to determine its MIME type.